# why call the method first will disconnect automatically after discovery

Tags: rx-java, rxandroidble

I am a newer for RxJava, and when i read the demo of rxandroidble library, I am wondering  why the first can disconnect the ble.

```
@OnClick(R.id.connect)
    public void onConnectToggleClick() {
        bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
                .flatMap(RxBleConnection::discoverServices)
                .first() // Disconnect automatically after discovery
                .compose(bindUntilEvent(PAUSE))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnUnsubscribe(this::updateUI)
                .subscribe(adapter::swapScanResult, this::onConnectionFailure);

        updateUI();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RxAndroidBle Observable behaviour](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle#observable-behaviour) of `establishConnection()` states, that only a single value is emitted, while the stream is not completed. It's also stated that unsubscribing the observable disconnects the connection.

> Whenever you are no longer interested in keeping the connection open you should unsubscribe from it which will cause disconnection and cleanup of resources.

But the `first()` operator emits a single value and completes the stream after. Since `bindUntilEvent(PAUSE)` will also complete the stream when pausing, you don't need to use `first()` at all. So just remove it and everything should be fine.